# Failure retry in EJB 3

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1

We have recently migrated our EJB 2 application to EJB 3.In EJB2 if some failures in onMessage container will be able to do retry the message on configured number of times however in EJB3 there is no such option.Could someone help on this.

Can we explicitly sleep the thread and do explicitly retry in onMessage?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using `@TransactionManagement(value=
   TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)` that is container managed
   transaction then on exception, message will be retired 10 time
   before the message is send to the DLQ.
2. If you are not using Activemq RA then, following two documents can
   be useful to you if you are having Container-Managed Transaction
   [Redelivery and Exception Handling](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24977/prog_details.htm#WLMDB452) and [Managing Rolled Back,
   Recovered, Redelivered, or Expired Messages](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24387/manage_apps.htm#JMSPG248)
3. If you are using ActiveMq resource adapter, use can use
   `MaximumRedeliveries`  [Resource Adapter properties](http://activemq.apache.org/resource-adapter-properties.html)
4. Else, if you want to retry only on specific exception then you can
   catch the exception and then send the message back to the same queue
   and with this additional property. [Activemq consume message after
   delay interval](http://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html) Also, set the retry count in the message header
   so that you can keep the track of the retries.

Comment: Where is item 1 documented in the spec?

Comment: http://activemq.apache.org/resource-adapter-properties.html is the link to first document

Comment: That is not a JavaEE spec. The OP has not indicated anywhere that they are using ActiveMQ. AFAIK, the answer will be different for every messaging implementation.